# JSOUP: Issue with HTML symbol &uml;

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

Following is the HTML string passing to JSOUP

```
<p id="pid">&uml;This is string using for testing</p>

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
String text = doc.getElementById("pid").text();
```

After extracting attribute text following is the result

```
¨This is string using for testing
```

But issue is for `¨This` hidden hex character is added to it. If I view string in notepad++ hexEditor `¨This` as `c2a854686973` (`Â¨This`)

Comment: Is this more of a text encoding problem that an HTML problem?  Best to check that everything is using the same text encoding.  Stray characters can often appear if encodings don't match.

Comment: I am using doc.getElementById("color").text() text method is returning unencoded text of particular node.So is there any other way to avoid it ?

Comment: `c2a8` is just how the unicode character [is encoded](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a8/index.htm). If you set the 'encoding' in notepad++ to `ANSI` it will be gone. Do you have any specific  problems when using it?

Answer (score 0):

> But issue is for `¨This` hidden hex character is added to it.

You can change the way you load the HTML code. Jsoup accepts to parse an `InputStream` as long as you provide the charset name.

#### SAMPLE

```
String s = "<p id=\"pid\">&uml;This is string using for testing</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()), "ASCII", "");
System.out.println(doc);
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p id="pid">&uml;This is string using for testing</p>
 </body>
</html>
```